# How do ionic, polar, hydrogen-bonding and non-polar compounds compare in TLC?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography

$R_\mathrm{f}$ decreases with increasing polarity. Does this mean a compound with an ionic bond would have the lowest $R_\mathrm{f}$? And nonpolar would have the highest $R_\mathrm{f}$?

Example: $\ce{RCOO- Na+}$ is ionic.  If the above is true it should have a lower $R_\mathrm{f}$ than cyclohexanol which has H-bonding?

Answer (score 2):

No, your analysis is wrong.

The nice thing about TLC is that you can pick the "paper" and the solvent to suit your analysis. So if you use benzene as the solvent then it won't "drag" ionized compounds along behind the solvent front very well.  If you use water ionized compounds do get dragged along nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The basis of each chromatography experiment — and that explicitly includes TLC — is that the retention factor is inherently dependent on the interactions between analyte, mobile phase and stationary phase. In silica gel–based chromatography, the staionary phase consists of $\ce{Si-OH}$ fragments and thus polar, hydrogen-bonding and ionic compounds interact well with the stationary phase while non-polar compounds don’t. Thus, as a general rule the more polar (i.e. more hydrogen-bonding, more ionic) compound will have a lower $R_\mathrm{f}$ value than the less polar one.

However note that $R_\mathrm{f}$ values are always dependent on stationary *and* mobile phase. By tuning your mobile phase, you can increase or decrease your compound’s $R_\mathrm{f}$ value to your desire — with the notable exception of very unpolar compounds that always run with the solvent front, practically all $R_\mathrm{f}$ values are possible. The most extreme case I actually used in the lab was $\text{ethyl acetate} : \text{methanol}\ 5:1$.